Search clob ignore case
I am trying to find  a phrase within a CLOB and I got it to work with the setup and query below.
My question is whether there a way I can do this without converting the case. For example, the CLOB is inserted with all lower case or mixed case. I'm looking for a CASE independent query if that makes sense. Note I'm not married to the LIKE command if there is something I can use that will ignore case.
Below is my test CASE.
create table recipes(
  seq_num NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
description VARCHAR2(50),
ingredients CLOB,
directions CLOB
);

INSERT into recipes (
   description, 
   ingredients,
   directions
) VALUES
('Italian Stuffed Peppers',
'
6 large bell peppers cut in half and seeds removed
1/4 cup olive oil divided
1 1/2 pounds ground chuck
2 cups cooked white rice
8 cloves garlic minced
1 cup low sodium beef stock
1 cup Pecorino Romano grated
1/4 cup parsley minced
1/4 cup basil chopped
1/4 teaspoon crushed hot red pepper flakes
2 teaspoons dried oregano
4 cups marinara sauce divided, see notes below
3/4 cup water
1 cup mozzarella grated
2 1/2 teaspoons kosher salt divided, plus more to taste
',
'XXX'
);

SELECT 
      seq_num, 
      ingredients 
FROM RECIPES
WHERE INGREDIENTS LIKE LOWER('%OLIVE%OIL%');



put a LOWER  (or UPPER) around both the column name (ingredients) and the comparison string.

You can create an Oracle Text index on the column:
CREATE INDEX recipes__ingredients__textidx ON recipes(ingredients)
  INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT;

Then:
SELECT seq_num, 
       ingredients 
FROM   RECIPES
WHERE  CONTAINS(ingredients, 'OLIVE OIL', 1) > 0;

Outputs:



SEQ_NUM
INGREDIENTS




1
6 large bell peppers cut in half and seeds removed1/4 cup olive oil divided1 1/2 pounds ground chuck2 cups cooked white rice8 cloves garlic minced1 cup low sodium beef stock1 cup Pecorino Romano grated1/4 cup parsley minced1/4 cup basil chopped1/4 teaspoon crushed hot red pepper flakes2 teaspoons dried oregano4 cups marinara sauce divided, see notes below3/4 cup water1 cup mozzarella grated2 1/2 teaspoons kosher salt divided, plus more to taste



fiddle

CLOB doesn't support "collate binary_ci/_ai", so the most common solutions are the LOWER/UPPER technique or regexp family of functions, if you don't want/can't use Oracle TEXT functionalities.
